# Motion tracked Video doesn't show up in the render or in the compositing tab

Tags: rendering, video, tracking

I tried to add a 3D object to a clip by following a youtube video. But clip doesn't show up in the render or in the compositing tab. It show up even in the camera view. I didn't change any settings.
please help.
Thank you.

[image: compositing tab]

And the  rendered images has only the cube in it like in the picture above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the alpha channel on the render layers. Without an alpha channel the "alpha over" will fail. Enable Film>Transparent so that the areas with no geometry will be "transparent".

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did enable transparent and it still doesn't the clip. Background and foreground renders with transparent backgrounds and then only white backround.

Comment: It worked I just reconnected the render layer and it worked. thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same challenge. However, marking it *Transparent* under *Film* under *Render Properties* made the motion tracked video clip show in render view.

That is, *Render Properties > Film > Transparent* turned ON.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a real answer but I also struggled really hard following cg geeks tutorial. i would feel sorry for people who try to do it. It just goes way too fast and he doesn't explain anything properly.It was very frustrating. However, I see you didn't set up the nodes properly. I did this same tutorial a few days ago and the result was quite successful. Maybe you can copy the nodes and change the images. Hope this saves a lot of time for you. Good Luck!

Link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/9a2z4LOy

Answer (score -1):

Or press N and open the side menu in tracking panel...and go to track menu under footage and change focal length from 0 to any number..may be you have accidentally changed focal length to 0 ..if yes then it will solve your problem.